# Turning a bra made up of a tensor product of two bras into a ket (and vice-versa)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, vectors

I know that in general the following statement is true: $$\langle\phi|\chi\rangle = \langle\chi|\phi\rangle^*  $$

And for the operator $A$ then the following identity also holds:
$$ \langle \psi| A|\phi\rangle = \langle\phi|A^\dagger |\psi \rangle$$

Does this mean that (1) implies (2)

$$| \psi\rangle = |\chi\rangle|\phi\rangle\tag1$$
$$\langle \psi|= \langle\phi|\langle\chi|\tag2$$

since I assume$$ \langle\psi|\psi\rangle = 1?$$

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with a composite system as it seems, you don’t need to change the order of $\psi$ and $\phi$ from (1) to (2), since the first (second) ket/bra always refers to the first (second) subsystem of your larger system. Along the same reasoning, you don’t need to change the order if the two kets/bras refer to two different degrees of freedom of the same system

Comment: So you mean the convention already suggests that only   the bra/kets that are in the same Hilbert space will interact with one another?

Comment: Yes, you can say it like that